# Import module from different directory with import_module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-importlib

I have a module in one directory that needs to be imported by a script in a different directory. However, whenever I try to import it, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`. I have to keep these in separate directories due to being in separate git repos. Here's an example of my file structure:

```
└─ Documents
   ├─ ModuleRepo
   │  └─ myModule.py
   └─ ScriptRepo
      └─ myScript.py
```

The script `myScript.py` takes the module name as a command line argument, and then imports it using:

```py
import importlib

def dynamic_import(module):
    return importlib.import_module(module)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('modulename', help='Specify the module to import', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    mymodule = dynamic_import(args.modulename)
```

If I navigate to `Documents/ModuleRepo` and try to run `python3 ../ScriptRepo/myScript.py myModule`, it gives the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myModule'`. If I move `myModule.py` into `Documents/ScriptRepo`, then it runs successfully - so I guess python is looking for modules only in the directory of the script being run. This is especially strange to me, since this exact setup worked for me a few months ago, but now seemingly doesn't.

My minimal goal is to be able to navigate to `Documents/ModuleRepo` and run `python3 ../ScriptRepo/myScript.py myModule`. Ideally (but not necessarily), I would like to be able to be able to run `myScript.py` from anywhere, using relative paths to both `myScript.py` and `myModule.py`.

I've browsed many existing questions about dynamic imports using `importlib`, and even asked one of my own earlier this year, but I still have no idea how to solve this problem of having modules in completely separate directories. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippets will allow you to load modules by explicitly defining the path to the required module(s):

For Python 3.5+ use:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module.name", "/path/to/file.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
foo.MyClass()
```

For Python 3.3 and 3.4 use:

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

foo = SourceFileLoader("module.name", "/path/to/file.py").load_module()
foo.MyClass()
```

(Although this has been deprecated in Python 3.4.)

For Python 2 use:

```
import imp

foo = imp.load_source('module.name', '/path/to/file.py')
foo.MyClass()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a path problem. At the very top of myScript.py add:

```
import sys 
sys.path.append('..')
```

This should allow it to find the module.